# Rdlc Running totals on page break in subreport

Tags: reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I need to display running subtotals in my rdlc report (VS2010) when a page breaks. I know you have RunningValue which can be used for this to display the subtotals in the page header or footer. The problem is that i need this in a subreport in which page header and footer aren't printed. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem (VS 2012). I've searched for an solution for hours, but it seems that you can't solve it with the rdlc-Report..

Note: You can't put the RunningValue in the page header or footer, an exception will occur ..